# How to add item to Extjs panel at exact position

Tags: extjs, panel, extjs3

I am adding an item to Extjs panel.

```
this.add(new_el);
this.doLayout();
```

It works fine. but in some cases I have to add {new_el} at exact position, not last.

For example penultimate one.

Can't find easy method in Extjs 3.2.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an ExJs component at a specific position (index)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629363/how-to-add-an-exjs-component-at-a-specific-position-index)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `insert()` instead of `add()`.

```
Mypanel.insert(0,cmp1);
Mypanel.insert(4,cmp2);
```