# How to add an ExtJs component at a specific position (index)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I have a ToolBar with some components (TextFields and Buttons) and I would like to dynamically add a component (TextField, for example) before the other components.

I tried `tbBar.add(myComponent);` without success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`Ext.container.AbstractContainer.insert`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-insert):

```
tbBar.insert(0, myComponent);
```

Comment: @Roberto: To indicate that an answer has been correct and has solved the problem stated in the question, you should mark the answer as "accepted".

Comment: It is also true for add panel to another panel at position specific.

Comment: I tried the same way but got this as error "Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined" in ext-all-debug.js

Comment: @strikers Looks more like a problem with the component that you add to the toolbar. This error message occurs if you use wrong xtypes.

Comment: @StefanGehrig: can you please tell me what exactly you mean by wrong xtypes?, do you mean a xtype that doesn't exist, then my xtype was correct. can there be other reason for this error? my code looks like this this.tabView.insert(1,{
    xtype: 'SimpleProjectDropdown',
    target: this,
    itemID: 'simpleDropdown'
   });

Comment: @strikers: Most likely `SimpleProjectDropdown` does not exist or is incorrect. Please show the definition of `SimpleProjectDropdown`. There should be something like `alias: 'widget.'` in there.

Comment: @strikers: You're sure that the `alias` for your component matches `widget.SimpleProjectDropdown`? And aliases should be written in lower-case but I'm not sure if this is enforced when instantiating a component.

Comment: stefan I got the issue, i forgot to add the view in requires section :p

Answer (score 3):

As an additional information, you can use "[Ext.container.AbstractContainer.container.items](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-cfg-items).indexOf" to get an index of a specific item in your container.

```
var index = container.items.indexOf(component);
container.insert(index, newComponent);
```