# how can I add an item in specific position

Tags: extjs

I have two forms which are extended from another form. I want to add some fields to one of them but not at the bottom of the form. I use add method and my items are added at the bottom of the form.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) 
Before to asking question please put your efforts or do some R&D because this type of question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629363/how-to-add-an-extjs-component-at-a-specific-position-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `insert` method on `container` instead of `container.add` to update the layout.

The `insert` takes two args,

- first : index to insert at
- second: the element to be inserted (could by a couple of other things)

In your case the `form` serves as the `container` so you need to do something like (assuming you are on Ext 5.x or lower):

```
var newField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Field', {});
var insertAt  = 3;

yourForm.insert(insertAt, newField);
```

Take a look at the fiddle as well: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2e0i

Edit: Removed the hacky way